# Excel - If any of 6 cells are > 0 divide by that number of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016, spreadsheet

[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet]

What I'm trying to do is the following:

Once **'Cell B19:B20'** and **'Row 21'** have a value, 'Row 22' divides **'Cell B19:B20'** between the amount of columns that have a cost value (**'Row 21'**).

For example:

> if only **D21** has a value the **D22=B19:B20**
>
> > if **D21 *AND* F21** have values then **D22=(B19:B20/2)**
> >
> > > if **D21 *AND* F21 *AND* H21** have values then **D22=(B19:B20/3)**

Basically calculate regardless of the order of columns but only accounting for the number of columns that have a value.

These are the formulas I have so far but they only calculate if the columns are in order (A, B, C, D) not random (A, C, H):

=IF((D21>0)*AND(E21>0)*AND(F21>0)*AND(G21>0)*AND(H21>0)*AND(I21>0),(B19/6),IF((D21>0)*AND(E21>0)*AND(F21>0)*AND(G21>0)*AND(H21>0),(B19/5),IF((D21>0)*AND(E21>0)*AND(F21>0)*AND(G21>0),(B19/4),IF((D21>0)*AND(E21>0)*AND(F21>0),(B19/3),IF((D21>0)*AND(E21>0),(B19/2),IF((D21>0),B19,0))))))

=IF((E21=0),0,IF((D22>0),D22,IF((E21>0)*AND(F21>0)*AND(G21>0)*AND(H21>0)*AND(I21>0),(B19/5),IF((E21>0)*AND(F21>0)*AND(G21>0)*AND(H21>0),(B19/4),IF((E21>0)*AND(F21>0)*AND(G21>0),(B19/3),IF((E21>0)*AND(F21>0),(B19/2),IF((E21>0),B19,0)))))))

=IF((F21=0),0,IF((D22>0),D22,IF((E22>0),E22,IF((F21>0)*AND(G21>0)*AND(H21>0)*AND(I21>0),(B19/4),IF((F21>0)*AND(G21>0)*AND(H21>0),(B19/3),IF((F21>0)*AND(G21>0),(B19/2),IF((F21>0),B19,0)))))))

=IF((G21=0),0,IF((D22>0),D22,IF((E22>0),E22,IF((F22>0),F22,IF((G21>0)*AND(H21>0)*AND(I21>0),(B19/3),IF((G21>0)*AND(H21>0),(B19/2),IF((G21>0),B19,0)))))))

=IF((H21=0),0,IF((D22>0),D22,IF((E22>0),E22,IF((F22>0),F22,IF((G22>0),G22,IF((H21>0)*AND(I21>0),(B19/2),IF((H21>0),B19,0)))))))

=IF((I21=0),0,IF((D22>0),D22,IF((E22>0),E22,IF((F22>0),F22,IF((G22>0),G22,IF((H22>0),H22,IF((I21>0),B19,0)))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This array (CSE) formula can solve the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Two values in Cell `A103` & in `B103` to dived with count of cells, (`A101:E101`) have value other than `ZERO`.
- Array formula in Cell `C103:`

  ```
  {=IF(COUNTIF(A101:E101,">0")=0,0,(A103:B103)/COUNTIF(A101:E101,">0"))}
  ```

**N.B:**

- Finish formula with **C**trl+**S**hift+**E**nter.
- `COUNTIF` formula in cell `F101`, justifies the **C**ount.
- Later on you may hide cell `F101`.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Wow thank you, that is exactly what I was trying to achieve. 

What does F101 (justifying the count) do? I tried with and without it and it works the same.

Comment: Glad to help you @Roman,, yes you can try even without `F101` formula ,, it's just for cross check,, or you may hide it,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 1):

You're using AND() in a weird way. Separate all the conditions that you want to combine with AND() with commas inside the brackets of the AND(). You are using the `*`, which already does what AND() does, too, so you're really doubling up the concept.

With AND() applied properly, your formula can start like this:

```
=IF(AND(D21>0,E21>0,F21>0,G21>0,H21>0,I21>0),B19/6),
    IF(AND(D21>0,E21>0,F21>0,G21>0,H21>0),(B19/5), [...]
```

and so on

A much shorter way to achieve the same result, though, is to look at the sum of the  cells.

```
=IF(Sum(D21:I21)>0,B19/6,
   IF(Sum(D21:H21)>0,B19/5,
      IF(sum(D21:G21)>0,B19/4,
        IF(sum(D21:F21)>0,B19/3,
          IF(sum(D21:E21)>0,B19/2,
             IF(D21>0,B19,0)
          )
         )
       )
    )
  )
```

Strictly speaking, you don't even need the `>0` in the conditions, since a `0` will evaluate to False and any number greater than zero will evaluate to True.

```
=IF(Sum(D21:I21),B19/6,
   IF(Sum(D21:H21),B19/5,
      IF(sum(D21:G21),B19/4,
         IF(sum(D21:F21),B19/3,
            IF(sum(D21:E21),B19/2,
               IF(D21,B19,0))))))
```

Go easy on the brackets. Sometimes, an extra pair of brackets can help where they are not really required, but don't apply them everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the help as well, the first response did solve my dilemma. Being a newb I had no clue that * is the same as AND(); Excel actually put that in there by itself when I entered the formula...any reason why it automatically edited the formula to include that?